# Android saving a video to a file

Tags: android, video, camera, save, samsung-mobile

I am designing an app with media functionality, one of which is video capturing. I am using a default call to the Camera instead of creating my own camera. The problem I am having is that after capturing a video it does not save into a video file I designated, but this problem, so far that I have tested, only happens on Samsung phones using the stock camera app. It works fine if I use the Google Camera on a Samsung phone or a phone from a different company. Is this a known bug for Samsung phones or am I just doing something wrong? If it is is there a workaround it?

Here is my videoHandler.

```
private void videoHandler() {
    Intent intent = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE );
    if ( intent.resolveActivity( getPackageManager() ) != null ) {
        File videoFile = null;
        try {
            videoFile = createVideoFile();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            System.out.println( "Error creating file." );
        }

        if ( videoFile != null ) {
            videoUri = Uri.fromFile( videoFile );
            intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri );
            intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1 );
            intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 15000000L );
            intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 6 );
            startActivityForResult( intent, VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE );
        }
    }
}
```

It calls createVideoFile, where I pre create a video file for a destination.

```
private File createVideoFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss" ).format( new Date() );
    String imageFileName = "MP4_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES );
    File video = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".mp4",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    this.videoUri = Uri.fromFile( video );
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE );
    mediaScanIntent.setData( this.videoUri );
    this.sendBroadcast( mediaScanIntent );
    return video;
}
```

Here is the error I get when I try calling the videouri in my onActivityResult.

```
01-17 16:37:23.254  27162-28145/com.example.kevinem.blitz E/ImageLoader﹕ /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MP4_20150117_163704_-918353230.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MP4_20150117_163704_-918353230.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromFile(BaseImageDownloader.java:160)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:88)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.getImageStream(BaseImageDecoder.java:93)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:73)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:264)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:237)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:135)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  Is there an exception stacktrace you can post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. Basically I found someone saying this.

> There is no requirement that a camera app follow the rules of ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE or ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE. Some will honor a specific requested output location. Some will not, and will return where they chose to store the image/video in the Uri contained in the result Intent delivered on onActivityResult(). Some may be completely broken and not tell you anything about where the image/video was stored, even if there was one stored.

Then I found in a different post that I had to manually retrieve it.

```
if (resultCode == -1) {
        //create a MediaScanner to save the vid into the indicate path
        new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
            private MediaScannerConnection msc = null;
            {
                msc = new MediaScannerConnection(
                        getApplicationContext(), this);
                msc.connect();
            }

            public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                msc.scanFile(name_vid, null);
            }

            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                msc.disconnect();

            }
        };
        Toast.makeText(this,"Video saved succesfull",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

name_vid is the path where you want to save the file in String format.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you are using `File.createTempFile( )`?

> Creates an empty file in the default temporary-file directory, using
>   the given prefix and suffix to generate its name. Invoking this method
>   is equivalent to invoking createTempFile(prefix, suffix, null).
>
> The Files.createTempFile method provides an alternative method to
>   create an empty file in the temporary-file directory. Files created by
>   that method may have more restrictive access permissions to files
>   created by this method and so may be more suited to security-sensitive
>   applications.

Not sure if this is producing the intended result. I recommend taking look at this documentation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)

particularly this piece.

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(path, "DemoPicture.jpg");
return file.exists();
```

**tl;dr**

I think this will fix yo shiz

```
 File video = new File(storageDir,  imageFileName + ".mp4")
```

Comment: Consider video.mkdirs() after instantiation.

Comment: I cannot test out the solution right now, but I will let you know as soon as I can.

Comment: I have tried just creating a regular File and it still does not work.